# backreference sed

Tags: sed

i would like to capture as backreference something like this.

Example:

```
(a-z)
```

But somehow anything I have tried, didn't work

I try this:

```
\(([a-z])\)\ or \('('[a-z]')'\)\
```

Comment: Are your trying to match the literal string `(a-z)`, or are you trying to match anything like `(a)`, `(b)`, etc?

Comment: your question is really obfuscated. what are you trying to do ? which string you are trying to match and out of what ? Some examples and expected outcomes would be really useful

Comment: I think you want `\((a-z)\)` (without `-r` or `-E`) or `(\(a-z\))` (with `-r` or `-E`).

Comment: I am trying to match one letter with parentheses

Comment: For example (f), (m), (n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>> echo "(f)" | sed 's/\(([a-z])\)/x\1x/'
x(f)x
```

`\(([a-z])\)` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
neko@takinolap : ~/test/sed
[0] % cat test.txt| sed -n '/([a-z])/p' 
this l(i)ne

neko@takinolap : ~/test/sed
[0] % cat test.txt
not this line
this l(i)ne
```

`()` are symbols. `\(\)` is selector, e.g.:

```
cat test.txt| sed -n 's/.*\(([a-z])\).*/\1/p'
(i)
```

`\(\)` places anything between it into numbered (per line) variable.

Comment: hope I got what you want right..

Comment: @don_crissti you actually don't if you just want to match it.. backreference is that feature that allows me to use \1 in expressions right?

Comment: whoops, didn't know it was the name of the feature.